# How to mock SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getCredentials()

Tags: junit, spring-security, mockito

When I try to mock

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getCredentials()
```

to get a `Map` of `UserDetails`, it's returning an error.

Can any one suggest the best way to get this done using Mockito?

Comment: show your test code and the exact exception

Answer (score 13):

The `SecurityContext` is stored inside `ThreadLocal`. Before running a test case , you have to use `SecurityContextHolder.getContext()` to create the `SecurityContext` for the current running thread and set the mocked `Authentication` for it which is equivalent to login.

At the end of the test case , you can use `SecurityContextHolder.clearContext()` to clear the `SecurityContext` from the `ThreadLocal` which is equivalent to logout.

Code wise, it looks like :

```java
    @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
    public class TestSecurity {
    
        @Mock
        private Authentication auth;
    
        @BeforeEach
        public void initSecurityContext() {
            when(auth.getCredentials()).thenReturn("mockedPassword");
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
        }
    
        @Test
        public void test() {
            //Access  getCredentials() which should return the mocked password
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getCredentials();
        }
    
        @AfterEach
        public void clearSecurityContext() {
            SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
        }
    
    }
```

Alternatively if you are interested, you can also consider using [`@WithMockUser`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#test-method-withmockuser) from the Spring Security Test to mock the `Authentication` rather than using `Mockito`.

Comment: Thanks for comments. But from SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getCredentials();
I need to get HashMap<String, String> , where I can get the user Name of logged in. for this line need to write the Unitcase. Can you please suggest further on this.

Comment: As `getCredentials()` returns the object type ,the actual type depends on your application. My example simply use "String" as the demonstration purpose but the idea is the same. So in you case when mocking getCredentials(), you configure it to return a `HashMap<String, String> ` based on your application logic.And what data to put in this HashMap is totally depends on how your application design. I cannot answer based on the current information that I know.